# Something with variables and parameters (Prepared statement)

Tags: php, mysql

I encountered a problem while making a prepared statement using php and mysql. For some reason my variables aren't right.

 Note: 
 - $mysqli = $conn

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `inschrijving` (`id`, `bezoeker_naam`, `bezoeker_voornaam`, `bezoeker_email`, `bezoeker_straat`, `bezoeker_huisnummer`, `bezoeker_postnummer`, `bezoeker_plaats`) VALUES (NULL, '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string('?')}');");}

                 $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $naam, $voornaam, $email, $straat, $huisnummer, $postcode, $plaats);

                 $naam = $_POST['naam'];
                 $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
                 $email = $_POST['email'];
                 $straat = $_POST['straat'];
                 $huisnummer = $_POST['nummer'];
                 $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
                 $plaats = $_POST['plaats'];

                 $stmt->execute();
```

The error I got was this:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of
>   parameters in prepared statement

I am new doing prepared statements and I need someone to point my faults out on this. It will really help me get to know more about prepared statements. :)

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the question marks. `('?')` -> `(?)`

Answer (score 0):

When working with prepared statements you shouldn't escape the bound variables:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `inschrijving` (`id`, `bezoeker_naam`, `bezoeker_voornaam`, `bezoeker_email`, `bezoeker_straat`, `bezoeker_huisnummer`, `bezoeker_postnummer`, `bezoeker_plaats`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare your POST variables above the prepare portion like so and remove the $mysqli->real_escape_string() from the statement:

```
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$straat = $_POST['straat'];
$huisnummer = $_POST['nummer'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$plaats = $_POST['plaats'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `inschrijving` (`id`, `bezoeker_naam`, `bezoeker_voornaam`, `bezoeker_email`, `bezoeker_straat`, `bezoeker_huisnummer`, `bezoeker_postnummer`, `bezoeker_plaats`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $naam, $voornaam, $email, $straat, $huisnummer, $postcode, $plaats)";
$stmt->execute();
```

You can put the $mysqli->real_escape_string() around the POST variables instead. For example:

```
$naam = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam']);
```

Lastly, make sure that all the variables are strings and don't forget to close the $stmt.

```
$stmt->close();
```